# Converting Unicode Number Subscripts to Standard Mathematica Subscript Notation

Tags: character-encoding, subscript, unicode

I am importing data

```
data={"t*α₁","α₁*α₄"}
```

But unfortunately, all of the subscripts are in Unicode:

```
FullForm[data]
List["t*α\:2081","α\:2081*α\:2084"]
```

i.e. subscript 1 is encoded as `\:2081` etc. Is there a way of converting these Unicode subscripts into Mathematica's more standard subscripts

```
desiredoutput={t Subscript[α, 1], Subscript[α, 1] Subscript[α, 4]}
```

Manipulating the data is difficult with the current Unicode formatting of the subscripts.

Comment: How many different variations do you have of those subscripts? If there aren't very many, then constructing replacement rules "by hand" could be the easiest way: `ToExpression[data] /. \[Alpha]₁ -> Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]` and similar others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code that works for subscript numerals, even if they represent a multi-digit number. You can modify the code to include also [other subscript characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2070).

```
subscriptNumerals = CharacterRange["₀", "₉"];
convertSubscripts[str_String] := ToExpression[str] /. 
  (sym_Symbol /; StringContainsQ[SymbolName[sym], subscriptNumerals]) :> 
   First@StringReplace[SymbolName[sym], (x : Except[subscriptNumerals]) ~~ 
    (i : subscriptNumerals ..) :> 
   Subscript[x, FromDigits[(First@*ToCharacterCode /@ Characters[i]) - 8320]]]

convertSubscripts["α₂ + t β₁₄ z + 3γ₁₇₈"]
(* Subscript["α", 2] + t z Subscript["β", 14] + 3 Subscript["γ", 178] *)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Just needed to modify the first line from "₁" to "₀" for the argument of CharacterRange to handle subscript 10 etc. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, right, of course :) Forgot about the zero ...